# Requesting merger of two accounts

Tags: support, status-completed

I have previously opened account with **TeX.SE** (user name : **velu**)and then another with motor vehicle maintenance and repair forum (user name:**velumani**). Later I couldn"t login in to the account of motor vehicle maintenance  and repair created seperately. If I give user name and password it opens one I have created with the TeX.SE and through that it logs in to attached forum of "motor vehicle maintenance  and repair".  Hence finally it will be convenient to have velu a/c only and ****request to merge velumani account to velu****.

Comment: I cannot find a user named velumani on the motor vehicle site. Can you link me to the profile page, question, or answer that is under the old account?

Comment: @Larry http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/2332/velumani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appears to only be one account: [velu](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2333/velu)  If you check that user, you can see that it's already linked to the [TeX site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19110/velu) and [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/68828/).

Unless I'm not understanding, I don't think this is a bug.

EDIT: Okay, I see it now.  Not sure why this user did not show up in search before.

Comment: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/2332/velumani

Comment: @velu, okay, NOW it's done.

Comment: thanks for merging 2 accounts in to a single.

Comment: @velu, you're welcome - sorry for not spotting it the first time.